# Is $e^{\pi \alpha}$ known to be transcendent for all real algebraic $\alpha$?

Tags: transcendental-numbers

The MathWorld article [Transcendental Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TranscendentalNumber.html) contains a reference to Yu. V. Nesterenko proof of transcendence of $e^{\pi \sqrt{2}}$. Is there a more general result about transcendence of $e^{\pi \alpha}$ for all real algebraic $\alpha$?

I observed that WolframAlpha returns an affirmative answers for questions like ["Is exp(pi * tan(pi/ 17)) a transcendental number?"](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Is+exp%28pi+%2a+tan%28pi%2F+17%29%29+a+transcendental+number%3F)

Comment: maybe not _all_. $\alpha = 0$ is a counter-example, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, I missed an obvious counterexample $\alpha=0$. But it seems this is the only counterexample, i.e. $e^{\pi \alpha}$ is a transcendental number for all non-zero real algebraic $\alpha$. It follows from the [Gelfond–Schneider theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem):

> If $a$ and $b$ are algebraic numbers where $a \notin \{0,\,1\}$ and $b \notin \mathbb{Q}$, then any value of $a^b$ is a transcendental number.

Just let $a=i$ and $b = -2 i \alpha$. Now we have  $b \notin \mathbb{Q}$ because 
$\Im(b) \ne0 $.

Comment: Yes. This is in Niven's little book in the G-S chapter, done just your way for $e^\pi.$ In the paragraph called "Remarks" immediately after Theorem 10.1.